# Can't create a file

Tags: android, file, ioexception

I'm trying to create a simple image file on Android and have the two following methods:
Creating the directory:

```
    private void createThumbnailDir() {
    File file = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + File.separator + "scouthouse",
            "scouthouse_thumbnails");
    this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("file", "file not created");
    }
}
```

Creating the file:

```
    private File createNewThumbnailFile() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    File file = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "scouthouse" + File.separator + "schouthouse_thumbnails" + File.separator
                    + sdf.format(date) + ".jpg");
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            return file;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I create the file the following IOException is raised:
       java.io.IOException: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

But the directory does exist when I check the file manager on my phone.

Edit:

More about the error:
stacktrace = null, so I only have the cause and the detailmessage, and they're both the same:      libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have this on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

?
EDIT:

```
      private File createThumbnailDir() {
        File file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        + File.separator + "scouthouse",
                "scouthouse_thumbnails");
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("file", "file not created");
            return file;
        }else {return null}
    }
```

Now:

```
  private File createNewThumbnailFile() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String filename= sdf.format(date) + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(createThumbnailDir(), filename); 

 try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    Toast.makeText(AndroidWebImage.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(AndroidWebImage.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(AndroidWebImage.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    return null;
}
```

[reference](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/save-file-to-sd-card.html)

Comment: I should've noted that in the story, yes I have the required permissions.

Comment: what is the line of the error? maybe you should put your logcat or something to complete your question.

Comment: If you already created the file in the first method why dont you use it to save the image? I will update my answer with that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving your file somewhere else? Your app might have no write permission.

Comment: I've made a comment on @Dyna above that also covers this.